# App not working when deployed locallly but working fine when deployed from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am stuck with one problem and i clueless how to debug it further. I have an small project developed using spring mvc. When i am deploying the application from the eclipse to configured tomcat it is working fine. But i am deploying the application manually on tomcat it is giving me when 404 when i hit the same endpoint.

What could be possible reason. Please guide me.

Comment: Are you hitting to the correct endpoint(IP, Port)?

Comment: yes when i hit the same endpoint after deploying from eclipse it works

Comment: Maybe, when you are deploying manually, it is being deployed to another endpoint.

Comment: How can i verify that ?

Comment: Tomcat defaults your application context to the directory name under webapps, i.e if your application is in webapps/myapp the url to your root will be localhost:8080/myapp/..